# Geth -- Is this possible to setup a private chain that only mining when accept TXs

Tags: go-ethereum

If I do not use the options dev and dev-period , can I  setup this kind of  private chain

Answer (score 0):

You can do it even on the ethereum mainnet but I think we cannot enforce this into the consensus